# npm doesn't honor git's "insteadOf" config when cloning from mirrors

Tags: node.js, npm

I have set up the following command to prevent npm from downloading NPM packages with the GIT protocol, as it is somehow blocked by my server :

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com
```

However, when running `npm install`, an error still occurs because a package tries to use the Git protocol, in the context of repo cloning from a mirror :

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/isaacs/js-yaml.git /home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-isaacs-js-yaml-git-dd3d7a8b: Cloning into bare repository '/home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-isaacs-js-yaml-git-dd3d7a8b'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/isaacs/js-yaml.git /home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-isaacs-js-yaml-git-dd3d7a8b: 
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/isaacs/js-yaml.git /home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-isaacs-js-yaml-git-dd3d7a8b: fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! git clone --template=/home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror git://github.com/isaacs/js-yaml.git /home/jenkins/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-isaacs-js-yaml-git-dd3d7a8b: github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Connection refused
```

I compared the modules that were installed into node_modules and the one that are declared in package.json, and the only missing one is `grunt-contrib-nodeunit`, which strangely doesn't depend on `js-yaml`... So why does it want to clone its repo then ? In any case, is there a way to force using HTTPS when specifying mirrors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get around this using (git:// instead of git@)

```
git config --global url."http://github.com".insteadOf git://github.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get around this problem with Gitlab CI. For some reason `npm` won't use my *insteadOf* rule, even though nothing is printed on the logs.
My solution is to edit the original file directly using `sed` :

```bash
sed -i -e "s/ssh\:\/\/git\@myrepo\.com\:/https\:\/\/myrepo\.com\//g" package.json
```

This will replace all `ssh://git@myrepo.com:` with `https://myrepo.com/` (note the trailing **:** is replaced by **/**).